# Checkbox checked or not in GOLANG

Tags: html, go

I am trying to build a simple web application using GOLANG. The goal is, when the user checks the  checkbox ,it has to call an API endpoint and when the user unchecks the checkbox , it has to call another API endpoint. Below is the form I have defined in the HTML with `action="p_up_dags/{{.}}"`.

**PS:** `.Result` is a list of strings.

```
{{ range .Result}}
<form action="/p_up_dags/{{.}}" method="POST">
     <br>  <input id={{.}} type="checkbox" name="{{.}}" value="{{.}}" >  {{.}}
    </form>
{{end}}
```

**GOLANG code :**

```
func p_up_dags(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
     d_name = mux.Vars(r)["name"]
    //do something to check if the checkbox is checked or not
    //Something like this
    if d_name is checked
       {
       //http.Get("blah/blah")
       }
    else
      {
       //http.Get("foo/foo")
      }
}

func main(){
     router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
     router.HandleFunc("/p_up_dags/{name}",p_up_dags)
}
```

Comment: this form dont't work so as form call when is button submit. You need javascript for call form . Goland use as sever language

Comment: You are right @Vadim . Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this thing myself by breaking it into two parts by changing the `action=` attribute in the Form when checkbox is checked and unchecked.
Below is the updated form with `action=""`.

```
{{range .Result}}
<form action="" name="{{.}}" method="POST">
    <label class="switch"> <input id="{{.}}" type="checkbox" class="box"  name="{{.}}" value="{{.}}"><span class="slider round"></span></label>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this.form,'{{.}}')">Pause/Unpause</button>
</form>
{{end}}
```

**JS CODE:**
Here, we check if the checkbox is checked or unchecked and then change the Form action respectively. `if checked then action="blah/blah" else action="foo/foo"`

```
<script>
function myFunction(form,result){
        var ch = document.getElementById(result)
        var formname = form.name;
        if(ch.checked == true){
            document[formname].action="/up_dags/"+result
        }
        else if(ch.checked == false){
            document[formname].action="/p_dags/"+result
        }
      }
</script>
```

**GOLANG code:**

```
func p_dags(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
   d_name := mux.Vars(r)["name"]
   _, err := http.Get(foo/foo/d_name)
}

func up_dags(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
   d_name := mux.Vars(r)["name"]
   _, err := http.Get(blah/blah/d_name)
}

func main(){
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/p_dags/{name}",p_dags)
    router.HandleFunc("/up_dags/{name}",up_dags)
}
```